# Building kernel for Android device

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I want to build kernel for device Samsung Galaxy core(GT-i8262). The chipset of the device is Qualcomm MSM8225 Snapdragon S4 Play(bootloader msm7627a). Kernel source available on http://opensource.samsung.com/reception.do is for Android JellyBean. I want to modify this kernel so that it can boot at least Android Marshmallow(Cyanogenmod aka Lineageos).

Their is a device similar to GT-i8262 which has same chipset having kernel which can boot Android Marshmallow(Cyanogenmod aka Lineageos) [here](https://github.com/I8552-CM/android_kernel_delos3geur).

I want to ask that how can I modify [this][2] source so that it can boot Marshmallow(Cyanogenmod aka Lineageos) for i8262.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note, that we are **not code-writer service**. We can *help* in your coding process by **resolving specific problems**, but we won't do *all work for you*.

Comment: Porting Android (AOSP and kernel) to new device is usually pretty tough task. So your question can't be answered easily. If you have some experience in kernel development and in Android development -- just get to work, and ask only very specific questions here. I'd recommend you to read [Embedded Android](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do) book and [Porting Linux on ARM board](http://free-electrons.com/pub/conferences/2015/captronic/captronic-porting-linux-on-arm.pdf) slides, to get a grasp on it.

Answer (score 0):

Porting Android on new device is difficult task. As per my knowledge Jellybean is based on the kernel version 3.4 version while Marshmallow is based on kernel version 3.18.

So you need to perform the below taks:

1. Backport the Linux kernel 3.18 patches to 3.4 kernel version.
2. Use the 3.18 kernel config file for Kernel compilation.
3. There are lot of changes on the Android Top layer (HAL and JNI layer) layer as well. So need to backport those changes as well.
4. Once you are able to compile the Android successfully; then only you can try to flash the image on your device.

You can follow the below link for flashing the image

https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-core/development/port-cyanogenmod-11-samsung-galaxy-core-t3468602

KEEP YOUR FINGERS CROSSED :)